# Bad configuration option: ControlPersist while scp with control master?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I am using `SCP` with `ControlMaster` to copy the files but somehow I am getting this error back -

```
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlPersist
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlPersist
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlPersist
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlPersist
command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: ControlPersist
```

Here is my shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/filetransfer/test01/primary
readonly SERVERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
export SERVERS_LOCATION_1=${SERVERS_LOCATION[0]}
export SERVERS_LOCATION_2=${SERVERS_LOCATION[1]}
export MAPPED_LOCATION=/data/snapshot
FILE_PARTITION=(550 274)

export dir3=$MAPPED_LOCATION/20140510

find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyFiles() {
  el=$1
  scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@$SERVERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/pp_week_1543_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@$SERVERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/pp_week_1543_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyFiles
parallel -j 5 do_CopyFiles ::: "${FILE_PARTITION[@]}"
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

This is only happening to this machine in which I am running my shell script. Other machine in which I am running my same shell script, it works fine. So some setting configuration is different I guess in this machine which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ControlPersist` option first appeared in OpenSSH 5.6. You're presumably using an older version.

If you don't have `ControlPersist`, you can explicitly kill the connection once you've done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer would be that you do not have the same version of `scp` on all systems and some of them do not support `-o ControlPersist`.

But is the ControlMaster really needed? Can you really measure the difference for the jobs you run?

Also you might want to look into rsync.